# ObservableCollection better than ObjectSet

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Why is it better (in WPF, C#, Entity Framework) to bind `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection` created upon the `ObjectSet` (from Entity Framework) rather than binding to `ObjectSet` directly?

**One more question:**
When I bind `ListBox` to `ObservableCollection`, any additions to the collection updates `ListBox`. Great. But `ObservableCollection` was created upon `ObjectContext` (in Entity Framework) and adding a new item to the collection doesn't add the item to the context... how to solve this????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ObservableCollection implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as `INotifyCollectionChanged`, both of which WPF uses to rebind elements to the UI. Thus, you could add an item to the ObservableCollection and immediately the UI would update with no code interaction from you. `ObjectSet` implements neither, and so doesnt get this functionality.

Comment: Terrific! And one other question, if I add a new item to the ObservableCollection then UI know it, but ObjectSet (context) doesn't know any changes. ...how to solve this problem???

Comment: Whenever you are adding the item to the ObservableCollection, also simply add that to your context. Ex: `MyComlexObject x = new MyComplexObject(); myObservableCollection.Add(x); myContext.ComplexObjects.Add(x);`

Answer (score 15):

(Note to your "One more question" point)

Entity Framework 4.1 offers a new feature which is especially useful in WPF applications - the **local view** of the object context. It is available through the `Local` property of `DbSet<T>`. `Local` returns an `ObservableCollection<T>` containing all entities of type `T` which are currently attached to the context (and not in state `Deleted`).

`Local` is useful because it stays automatically in sync with the object context. For example: You can run a query to load objects into the context ...

```
dbContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Country == "Alice's Wonderland").Load();
```

... and then expose the objects in the context as an `ObservableCollection` ...

```
ObservableCollection<Customer> items = dbContext.Customers.Local;
```

... and use this as the `ItemsSource` of some WPF ItemsControl. When you add or remove objects to/from this collection ...

```
items.Add(newCustomer);
items.Remove(oldCustomer);
```

... they get automatically added/removed to/from the EF context. Calling `SaveChanges` would insert/delete the objects into/from the database.

Likewise adding or removing objects to/from the context ...

```
dbContext.Customers.Add(newCustomer);
dbContext.Customers.Remove(oldCustomer);
```

... updates automatically the `Local` collection and fires therefore the notifications for the WPF binding engine to update the UI.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx) is an overview about `Local` in EF 4.1.

Comment: How would you handle validation if you did things this way? Would you have the entity models implement IDataErrorInfo/INotifyDataError?

Comment: @Cocowalla: I believe I did it this way, yes. But I'm not working with WPF anymore since some time, so I can't really tell what's the best way. You better ask a separate question if you'd like professional answers :)

Comment: I already asked a seperate question, but thanks for your reply :)